# Reference dynamic text from another document within Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I want to create a document that has ten pages in it (ten pages, each page a new set of unique information).  I want that document to pull from ten unique, single page documents that users can update.  I want the updates in the unique documents to populate in the conglomerate document.

Is this possible with Google Docs?

I have seen that dynamic text can be linked between Google Sheets, or between Google Sheets and Google Docs but I want to do dynamic text from Google Doc to Google Doc.

Comment: Welcome to to [webapps.se]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask]. From the last link: Have you [thoroughly searched for an answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/search) before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this with Docs, but it would require a 3rd party application that reads/writes the data from one Doc to the other. I haven't found a suitable one yet but it's technically possible to create one with the APIs available.